# Can you name a new window opened with Chrome command line?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, command-line, cmd

I have a window which is named "childwin" but I would like to open it with a command line.  Currently the window would be opened in a batch file like this:

```
start "" chrome --kiosk "E:\index.html"
```

Is there a way to name the window being opened as I do with the `window.open(url, NAME)` Javascript command?

Comment: I didn't find an answer to this specific but I am able to set the name with the `window.name = "myWindowName"`; Javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JavaScript `window.name = "childwin"`in the HTML file and the name will be set.

Comment: I was looking for just this!

Comment: Too bad this doesn't do what the OP asked -- to specify the window name on the command line.